# Solving an integral within an integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

I have been trying for a while now to solve the following integral:

$$ \int_0^t e^{-ct} \left(\int_0^t(1-M_r t)^a e^{ct} dt\right) (1-M_r t)^{-(a+1)} dt  $$

I know the answer is: $$ \frac {1}{M_r^2} [(1-M_r t) \ln( (1-M_r t) -1)] $$

the only approach I can think of is to use integration by parts and setting the integral within the integral to be the function which is differentiated. However, this does not seem to lead to the answer. Does anybody have ANY idea? A reference, term I could search. Literally anything that could point me to the right trail would be helpful.

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484518/how-do-you-integrate-by-parts-with-two-integrals) might help you, it helped me a lot

Comment: Hmmmmmm, I don't know if the Laplace transform will be easily computable for $ (1-M_r t) ^{-(a+1)} $. The book you had linked in there is awesome though.

Comment: Are $M,a,c$ constants? Do we know anything about these (i.e. are any non-negative?)

Comment: Correct everything is constant, but a is NOT an integer.
Am I correct in saying this is a double integral? and can be written as follows:
$ \int_{y=0}^{y=t} \int_{x=0}^{x=y}  (1-M_r x}^a e^{cx} e^{-cy} (1- M_r y)^{-(a+1)}  $

Comment: All three constants M, a, c are positive

Comment: @Filip It's okay, it was worth a try, I wasn't suggesting that you Laplace transform your integral, I was simply showing another example of where integration by parts has been carried out with one integral within another as [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484518/can-you-integrate-by-parts-with-one-integral-inside-another), the Laplace transform has nothing to do with the question I asked. It was just used to give some background for an example of such an integral of an integral.

Comment: @BLAZE I am reading that book you linked too, I like it alot. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Filip You're welcome :)